# Where is the theorem related to the construction of countable admissible ordinals by Turing machines with oracles?

Tags: logic, reference-request, ordinals, turing-machines, oracles

Wikipedia contains the following information in the article ["Admissible ordinal"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_ordinal):

> By a theorem of Sacks, the countable admissible ordinals are exactly those constructed in a manner similar to the Church-Kleene ordinal, but for Turing machines with oracles. [Reference: Friedman, Sy D. (1985), "Fine structure theory and its applications"]

I have found the referenced paper, but I cannot seem to find any reference to this theorem there.

Question: where can I find this theorem? What is its name (or identifier)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[S.-D. Friedman's paper](http://www.logic.univie.ac.at/%7Esdf/papers/fine.structure.theory.pdf) mentions Sacks' result on page $265$ (the first page of lecture $3$). It's just a one-line mention, though, so it's not really helpful - and Friedman's bibliography doesn't mention Sacks' paper.

The paper you want is Sacks' [Countable admissible ordinals and hyperdegrees](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0001870876901870/1-s2.0-0001870876901870-main.pdf?_tid=71e4f14d-88f9-4e4a-8950-dde2046ddc25&acdnat=1548990913_fc95b0e3ed3ee69e2e0ee26f9835de9d) - namely, you want the first half of Theorem $4.26$. I don't think it has a name.

Additionally, the paper *Note on admissible ordinals* by *H.* Friedman and Jensen contains an alternate forcing-free proof of Sacks' theorem. The volume it's in ([*Syntax and semantics of infinitary languages*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/bfb0079683)) has some delightful material but poorly typeset and a bit hard-to-find.

---

A couple quick remarks about the result:

- The "computability-to-admissibility" half, that $\omega_1^r$ is admissible for all reals $r$, is Exercise VII.$1.13$ in [Sacks' higher recursion theory book](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235422631#toc). It's just the relativized version of showing that $\omega_1^{CK}$ is admissible: you prove that $L_{\omega_1^r}[r]\models$ KP, by exactly the same argument *(remember that if $M$ is an admissible set then $L^M=L_{M\cap Ord}$ is also admissible)*.
- There's a quick proof that every *successor* admissible is the $\omega_1^{CK}$ of some real: namely, if $\beta$ is admissible and $\alpha$ is the next admissible above $\beta$, let $G$ be $Col(\omega,\beta)$-generic over $L_\alpha$. $G$ essentially is an $\omega$-copy of $\beta$, so trivially $\omega_1^G>\beta$; but $Col(\omega,\beta)\in L_\alpha$, [set forcing preserves admissibility](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/257798/history-of-forcing-over-admissible-sets), and no real in an admissible set computes the height of that admissible set, so we get $\omega_1^G\le\alpha$. This means $\omega_1^G=\alpha$ since $\omega_1^G$ is admissible. **So the interesting part is showing that admissible limits of admissibles occur as $\omega_1^{CK}$s.**
- It's also worth noting that for $\alpha$ admissible, we may indeed need to step outside of $L_\alpha$ to find a real whose $\omega_1^{CK}$ is $\alpha$. In particular, if there is some $r\in L_\alpha$ with $\omega_1^r=\alpha$, then $L_\alpha$ will be *locally countable* (= $L_\alpha\models$ "every set is countable"). But plenty of countable admissible $\alpha$s don't give rise to locally countable levels of $L$! One way to see that this is plausible is to observe that if $\alpha$ is an admissible limit of admissibles (= "recursively inaccessible"), then every real in $L_\alpha$ is contained in some admissible $L_\beta$ with $\beta<\alpha$ and so no real in $L_\alpha$ can code a copy of $\alpha$, so the "obvious" reason for a level of $L$ to be locally countable doesn't apply to admissible limits of admissibles (although of course many such ordinals *do* yield locally countable levels of $L$). But there are even successor admissible ordinals not giving rise to locally countable levels of $L$ (take e.g. $\alpha=$ the image of $\omega_1$ under the Mostowski collapse of a countable $M\prec H_{\omega_2}$ and look at the next admissible above $\alpha$).

Comment: There is one detail here that I want to clarify: assuming that $\alpha$ is an arbitrary countable (computable or uncomputable) ordinal greater than $0$ and a family $F_\alpha$ of Turing machines is [equipped with an oracle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2909833/276097) for a copy of $\omega_{\alpha}^{\text{CK}}$, can we assume that for any ordinal $\beta < \omega_{\alpha+1}^{\text{CK}}$, there exists the corresponding machine that belongs to $F_\alpha$ and computes $\beta$?

Comment: @lyricallywicked You seem to be conflating $\omega_{\alpha+1}^{CK}$ (the $(\alpha+1)$th admissible ordinal) and $\omega_1^\alpha$ (the first admissible ordinal $>\alpha$). For example, taking $\alpha=\omega+17$, the first admissible above $\alpha$ is just $\omega_1^{CK}$ but $\omega_{\alpha+1}^{CK}$ is quite huge; this is analogous to $\vert\omega_1+17\vert<\aleph_{\omega_1+17}$. (Also, when you say "a family," I presume you mean the family of *all oracle machines* - otherwise, *what* family do you have in mind? Certainly some families won't have any interesting computational power at all ...)

Comment: The question I think you mean to ask is: suppose $r$ is a real coding a copy of a countable ordinal $\alpha$, and $\beta<\omega_1^{CK}(\alpha)$ (that is, $\beta$ is less than the first admissible $>\alpha$). Then must we have $r\ge_Ts$ for some real $s$ coding a copy of $\beta$? ("$a\ge_Tb$" here means, "there is some index $e$ for an oracle Turing machine such that $\Phi_e^b=a$.") The answer to this is **yes**: we clearly have $\omega_1^{CK}(r)>\alpha$, and by the first part of Sacks' theorem we know that $\omega_1^{CK}(r)$ is admissible, so $\omega_1^{CK}(r)>\beta$. Now use the definition...

Comment: 1/3: no, I am not conflating, your first assumption was right: when I write $\omega_{\alpha+1}^{\text{CK}}$, I mean the $(\alpha+1)$th admissible ordinal. I am trying to clarify [this comment on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2904721/is-it-possible-to-construct-a-model-of-oracle-turing-machines-that-correspond-to#comment6000065_2904721).

Comment: 2/3: For example, let $r_1$ denote a particular real that encodes a particular copy of $\omega_1^{\text{CK}}$. Consider Turing machines with an oracle for $r_1$. Let $\beta_1$ denote the supremum of all ordinals that are computable by such machines. Question $1$: is $\beta_1$ equal to $\omega_2^{\text{CK}}$? If yes, is this process applicable to all countable ordinals? That is, instead of $\omega_2^{\text{CK}}$, the ordinal $\omega_{\alpha+1}^{\text{CK}}$ could be produced by a similar process.

Comment: 3/3: For example, let $r_\omega$ denote a particular real that encodes a particular copy of $\omega_\omega^{\text{CK}}$ (the smallest limit of admissibles; this ordinal is described in section 2.2 of the book “A zoo of ordinals” by David A. Madore). Consider Turing machines with an oracle for $r_\omega$. Let $\beta_\omega$ denote the supremum of all ordinals that are computable by such machines. Question $2$: is $\beta_\omega$ equal to $\omega_{\omega+1}^{\text{CK}}$?

Comment: @lyricallywicked Oh, I'm sorry, the misread was on my end: in your original comment I read "$\omega_\alpha^{CK}$" as just "$\alpha$." Meanwhile, your additional questions are on the right track, but aren't phrased correctly. Certainly *some* copies of (say) $\omega_1^{CK}$ will let you compute gigantic ordinals; you want to ask about "minimally complicated" (or "optimal" in some sense) copies. Once phrased appropriately, the answer is **yes**.

Comment: @lyricallywicked See [my answer to your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3097729/28111).

Comment: > you want to ask about "minimally complicated" (or "optimal" in some sense) copies < Yes, yes, that's essentially the crux of [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2904721/): what is the minimally complicated copy $r_1$ of $\omega_1^{CK}$ such that for any ordinal $\beta < \omega_2^{CK}$  there exists a Turing machine that computes $\beta$ with an oracle for $r_1$?

Comment: @lyricallywicked As I've said elsewhere I think, there is no "the" $r_1$ here. There are only reals which are optimally simple *in a weak sense* - in that they compute the bare minimum ordinals possible - but that's a very wide class of reals ...

Comment: The "what is the minimally complicated copy" part can be replaced with "what is an example of _any_ class of reals that encode a copy".

Comment: @lyricallywicked We can whip up an example via [Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$](): for a computable ordinal $\alpha$, let $e_\alpha$ be the least notation $n\in\mathcal{O}$ with $\vert n\vert_\mathcal{O}=\alpha$. The set $D=\{e_\alpha:\alpha<\omega_1^{CK}\}$ and the relation $<_\mathcal{O}\upharpoonright D^2$ together provide a linear order isomorphic to $\omega_1^{CK}$ with domain $D\subseteq\omega^2$, and this gives an appropriately "simple" copy (namely, all this data exists in $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$, which doesn't contain any copies of $\omega_2^{CK}$).