# Extensions of the Turing jump

Tags: computability, ordinals, oracles

The Turing jump $0^{(\alpha)}$ is defined for ordinals $\alpha<\omega_1^{\mathit{CK}}$ with

- $0^{(0)} = \varnothing$,
- $0^{(\alpha+1)}$ is the diagonal halting problem using $0^{(\alpha)}$ as an oracle,
- $0^{(\lambda)}$ for a limit $\lambda$ is the effective join of the $0^{(\lambda_n)}$ for a computable sequence $\lambda_n$ of ordinals with computable notations and $\lambda_n\rightarrow\lambda$.

The set of natural numbers corresponding to ordinal notations in this scheme is denoted by $\mathcal O$ and $\omega_1^\mathit{CK}$ is the supremum of the ordinals encoded in $\mathcal O$. The hyperjump $X\mapsto\mathcal O^X$ allows the sequence in the limit case of the above definition to be $X$-computable.

This suggests the following extension of the Turing jump beyond $\omega_1^\mathit{CK}$:

- $0^{(\omega_1^\mathit{CK})}=\mathcal O$
- $0^{(\omega_{\alpha+1}^\mathit{CK})} = \mathcal O^{0^{(\omega_{\alpha}^\mathit{CK})}}$
- $0^{(\omega_\lambda^\mathit{CK})}$ for a limit $\lambda$ is the effective join of the $0^{(\omega_{\lambda_n}^\mathit{CK})}$ for a $0^{(\omega_{\alpha}^\mathit{CK})}$-computable sequence of ordinals with $0^{(\omega_{\alpha}^\mathit{CK})}$-computable notations for some $\alpha<\lambda$ and $\lambda_n\rightarrow\lambda$.

1. Is this construction well-defined? In particular, is it true that the hyperjump of each admissible $\omega_\alpha^\mathit{CK}$ allows us to denote ordinals up to $\omega_{\alpha+1}^\mathit{CK}$, and the definition for the limit case up to $\omega_{\lambda}^\mathit{CK}$?
2. What can we say about the ordinals that obtain notations this way? What is their supremum?

---

The second part of my question is less rigorous and assumes that there are meaningful answers to the above questions. It seems natural to further abstract from the construction described above: Whenever the process we have defined so far reaches a limit, we can take the set of natural numbers corresponding to notations in the scheme defined so far as an oracle for the next ordinal, define another jump operator and enumerate its applications using the already-defined ordinals. If we manage to formalize this creation of new jump operators and their limits in a systematic way, we will again have ordinal stages and this process will have a supremum. At this point we could devise a scheme for creating jump operator schemes, and so on. My question is: Can this abstraction process be formalized in a way that cannot be extended meaningfully beyond its supremum? What would that supremum look like? I've found [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jsl/1183740554)<sup>1</sup> on mastercodes thanks to this site but I don't understand the notation in it and I'm not sure the idea is the same.

Another perspective on this hyper-abstraction process could be a computational one: I might very well be mistaken, but it seems to me that at each individual stage I would be able to find a canonical way to generalize the abstraction to an abstraction on an even higher level. I could write a Turing machine (using oracles) not only computing ordinal notations, but also one computing codes of Turing machines computing ordinal notations, and so on. But could there be a "final" such Turing machine able to carry out all the work I would be doing there?

<sup>1</sup>Harold T. Hodes: *Jumping Through the Transfinite: The Master Code Hierarchy of Turing Degrees,* The Journal of Symbolic Logic, Vol. 45, No. 2 (Jun., 1980), pp. 204-220; [DOI: 10.2307/2273183](https://doi.org/10.2307/2273183), [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2273183)

Comment: I have two quick comments. First, I think the paper on mastercodes is not what you're looking for but is highly relevant - it demonstrates how a more model-theoretic line of thought can avoid, at least for a while, the notation-based issues around iterating the Turing jump. Basically, rather than thinking in terms of iterating the Turing jump at all, we just think about looking at the theories of structures in a particular sequence, and this happens to after the fact connect with the Turing jump. (cont'd)

Comment: Second, re: your last sentence keep in mind that (under reasonable consistency assumptions) ZF cannot prove that there is a sequence of $\omega_1$ distinct Turing degrees. Consequently there's no hope of a "concrete" way to iterate the Turing jump an arbitrary countable ordinal number of times. This is closely related to the fact that there is no "concrete" way to assign to each countable ordinal a well-ordering of a set of natural numbers with the same ordertype.

Comment: @NoahSchweber 1: Thanks for elaborating on that method. I am interested in a "bottom up" approach though because I would like to capture a notion of "describability" for ordinals (in terms of previously defined ordinals). 2: Sure, what I want to find out is basically what kinds of ordinals can be reached with this process. For example, the first part of my question is about the first step beyond the hyperjump; do you know if there are any results on that?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process you have in mind can be formalized as follows. We define a sequence of **Turing degrees** (*not* individual sets of natural numbers) as follows. I'm going to talk about (hyper)jump sequences along well-orderings rather than families of fundamental sequences of ordinals, since the former is ultimately much easier to work with.

I'll use the following definition (although there are many equivalent ones out there). Suppose I have a map $\mathfrak{m}:\mathcal{P}(\omega)\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(\omega)$, which below will be either the jump or hyperjump operator. Given a set $A$ and a well-ordering $R$ of $\omega$ (*not* just an ordinal, a literal relation on the natural numbers) we let the **$\mathfrak{m}$ sequence along $R$ starting with $A$** be the unique set $U$ such that

$$U_k=\begin{cases}
A &\mbox{ if $k$ is the $R$-least element},\\
A\oplus \mathfrak{m}(U_l) & \mbox{ if $l$ is the immediate predecessor of $k$ in $R$, and}\\
A\oplus \{\langle i,j\rangle: j<_Rk, i\in U_j\} & \mbox{ if $k$ is an $R$-limit point.}\\
\end{cases}$$

where "$X_n$" is the $n$th column of $X$, namely $\{m: \langle m,n\rangle\in X\}$. Folding $A$ in at each level isn't something we ever have to do, but it cleans things up a bit in my opinion.

It's a good exercise to prove that a unique such $U$ indeed exists. *(HINT: transfinite recursion/induction.)*

---

- We let $r_0=\bf 0$ be the degree of the computable sets.
- Having defined $r_\alpha$, we let $r_{\alpha+1}={r_\alpha}'$.
- Now suppose $\lambda$ is a limit and we've defined $r_\alpha$ for all $\alpha<\lambda$. There are now four cases:

  - **Small $\lambda$.** suppose there is some $\alpha<\lambda$ such that there is a well-ordering $R$ of $\omega$ which has ordertype $\lambda$ is computable from $r_\alpha$. Fixing some such $\alpha$, some representative $A\in r_\alpha$, and some $R$ as above, we let $r_{\lambda}$ be the degree of the jump sequence starting with $A$ along $R$.

    - Wait, is that even well-defined? **Yes it is**, but this is nontrivial. It's easiest to first consider a single appropriate choice of $\alpha$. It turns out that if $R,S$ are isomorphic well-orderings of $\omega$ which are each computable from some degree ${\bf a}$, then for any $A,B\in{\bf a}$ the jump sequence along $R$ starting with $A$ is Turing-equivalent to the jump sequence along $S$ starting with $B$. This isn't too hard to prove (see Sacks' book), but it should be surprising in light of various examples of the opposite phenomenon (e.g. with iterated consistency principles or with the Ershov hierarchy). Now it's a good exercise to generalize this to show that the choice of $\alpha$ doesn't matter either.
  - **Medium $\lambda$.** Suppose the case above doesn't hold, but there is some $\alpha<\lambda$ such that $\lambda=\omega_1^{CK}(\alpha)$. Fixing the least such $\alpha$, we let $r_\lambda=\mathcal{O}^{r_\alpha}$.
  - **Large $\lambda$.** Suppose $\lambda$ is neither small nor medium, but there is some $\alpha<\lambda$ and some $r_\alpha$-computable well-ordering $R$ of $\omega$ such that the set of admissible ordinals $<\lambda$ has ordertype $R$. In this case we follow the "small $\lambda$" approach above with hyperjump in place of jump; and as there, we have a crucial - and nontrivial - well-definedness result.
  - **Ginormous $\lambda$.** Suppose $\lambda$ is neither small, medium, or large. Then this process ends.

It turns out that the stopping point of this construction - that is, the first ginormous ordinal - is exactly the first **recursively inaccessible** ordinal, that is, the first ordinal which is both admissible and a limit of admissibles. The proof is basically unwinding the definitions and applying [Sacks' connection between computability and admissibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3095770/28111).  It's worth noting that the first recursively inaccessible ordinal is galactically larger than the first limit of admissibles, but is in turn cosmically smaller than the first $2$-admissible; see [this survey of Madore](http://www.madore.org/%7Edavid/math/ordinal-zoo.pdf) for some useful information.

More generally, if we replace ${\bf 0}$ with $deg(A)$ for some $A$ in the start of the construction, the stopping point is the least $\kappa$ such that there is an admissible set $\mathbb{M}$ of height $\kappa$ with $A\in \mathbb{M}$ and $\mathbb{M}\models$ "Every set is contained in an admissible set."

---

Finally, let me end by saying a bit about how "long jump sequences" can be created:

- The approach you've taken is in some sense the most direct: we keep writing down concrete operators which get us a bit further each time, and take the sup of what we can get along them as above.
- The "mastercodes" approach is more model-theoretic: rather than thinking of operators on *reals* we think of operators on *structures*, and the degrees we look at are the degrees of the theories of those structures (or similar objects). This has a surprising advantage of providing *canonical representatives* of those degrees, namely the actual reals coding the relevant theories themselves.
- Finally, there's the "higher type oracle" approach. We can define "$\omega_1^{CK}(\mathfrak{F})$" for a higher type function $\mathfrak{F}$ as the least ordinal with no $\mathfrak{F}$-computable copy via Kleene's theory of computability in higher types. Even relatively concrete choices of $\mathfrak{F}$ get us far beyond the first recursively inaccessible ordinal. Madore's survey I linked to above refers to these frequently.

Comment: Very nice. I have two questions: (1) Is there a way to extend this construction beyond the first ginormous ordinal, so that we can say "if $\lambda$ is ginormous, replace $\mathbf{0}$ with $deg(A_\lambda)$ and start over again"? Or in general, can we create an ordinal hierarchy of jump operators from already defined jump operators and say "whenever we reach an $\alpha$-level ordinal, apply the $\alpha$-jump"? (2) Where can I find more systematic information on the "higher type oracle" approach you mention?